# Convert PHP object to string

Tags: php, object

I've got this code:

```
<?php
   $imageVar = $entry->field('logo')->generate();
   $path = $imageVar;
   $file = basename($path, ".svg");
   $rest = substr($file, 0, -9);
?>

<img src="<?php echo $imageVar; ?>" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='files/media/images/partners/<?php echo $rest; ?>.png'" title="<?php echo $entry->field('name')->value(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $entry->field('name')->value(); ?>" >
```

Its working but I get an error like this:

```
[13-Apr-2016 10:00:49 GMT] 
PHP Warning: basename() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /wwwroot.wwwnew/templates/customcatalog_partnerpool_leser_1_1.html5 on line 58
#0 [internal function]: __error(2, 'basename() expe...', '/wwwroot.wwwnew...', 58, Array)
#1 /wwwroot.wwwnew/templates/customcatalog_partnerpool_leser_1_1.html5(58): basename(Object(Contao\FilesModel), '.svg')
#2 /wwwroot.wwwnew/system/modules/core/library/Contao/BaseTemplate.php(88): include('/wwwroot.wwwnew...')
#3 /wwwroot.wwwnew/system/modules/core/library/Contao/Template.php(277): Contao\BaseTemplate->parse()
#4 /wwwroot.wwwnew/system/modules/core/classes/FrontendTemplate.php(46): Contao\Template->parse()
#5 /wwwroot.wwwnew/system/modules/pct_customelements_plugin_customcatalog/PCT/CustomElements/Plugins/CustomCatalog/Core/CustomCatalog.php(436): Contao\FrontendTemplate->parse()
#6 /wwwroot.wwwnew/system/modules/pct_customelements_plugin_customcatalog/PCT/CustomElements/Plugins/CustomCatalog/Frontend/ModuleReader.php(145): PCT\CustomElements\Plugins\CustomCatalog\Core\CustomCatalog->render()
#7 /wwwroot.wwwnew/system/modules/core/modules/Module.php(283): PCT\CustomElements\Plugins\CustomCatalog\Frontend\ModuleReader->compile()
#8 /wwwroot.wwwnew/system/modules/pct_customelements_plugin_customcatalog/PCT/CustomElements/Plugins/CustomCatalog/Frontend/ModuleReader.php(95): Contao\Module->generate()
#9 /wwwroot.wwwnew/system/modules/core/elements/ContentModule.php(59): PCT\CustomElements\Plugins\CustomCatalog\Frontend\ModuleReader->generate()
#10 /wwwroot.wwwnew/system/modules/core/library/Contao/Controller.php(484): Contao\ContentModule->generate()
#11 /wwwroot.wwwnew/system/modules/core/modules/ModuleArticle.php(213): Contao\Controller::getContentElement(Object(Contao\ContentModel), 'main')
#12 /wwwroot.wwwnew/system/modules/core/modules/Module.php(283): Contao\ModuleArticle->compile()
#13 /wwwroot.wwwnew/system/modules/core/modules/ModuleArticle.php(67): Contao\Module->generate()
#14 /wwwroot.wwwnew/system/modules/core/library/Contao/Controller.php(417): Contao\ModuleArticle->generate(false)
#15 /wwwroot.wwwnew/system/modules/core/library/Contao/Controller.php(277): Contao\Controller::getArticle(Object(Contao\ArticleModel), true, false, 'main')
#16 /wwwroot.wwwnew/system/modules/core/pages/PageRegular.php(133): Contao\Controller::getFrontendModule('0', 'main')
#17 /wwwroot.wwwnew/system/modules/core/controllers/FrontendIndex.php(285): Contao\PageRegular->generate(Object(Contao\PageModel), true)
#18 /wwwroot.wwwnew/index.php(20): Contao\FrontendIndex->run()
#19 {main}
```

But I have no idea how to solve the problem.

Comment: what is the output of `$path`?

Comment: $imageVar is an object, can you use `print_r($imageVar);` and display us the result ?

Comment: The output of $patch is: "assets/images/d/1900-cd29b6dd.png" and $imageVar got the same output.

Comment: You should do what @MathieuLescaudron suggested probably you will need access some object property like path but with this code we can't help you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should understand diffrence between object and string

```
$imageVar = $entry->field('logo')->generate();
            $path = $imageVar;
```

here $imageVar is become object not string so you change first bez
 your function  $file = basename($path, ".svg"); is require string not object

if you are doing this in php then use   (string) befour the $imageVar now your code will be

```
 $imageVar = $entry->field('logo')->generate();
                $path = (string)$imageVar;
```

try

Comment: That works for 90% :) but not for this one: $imageVar = \FilesModel::findByUuid($result->logo);  $path = (string)$imageVar; The error says PHP Recoverable error: Object of class Contao\FilesModel could not be converted to string in /wwwroot.wwwnew/templates/customcatalog_partnerpool_leser_1_1.html5 on line 57

Comment: $imageVar = \FilesModel::findByUuid($result->logo); this is not mention in your above code

Comment: Yes, I just saw it now, I thought its the same.

Comment: no it's not same show me full code

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php try

Comment: This is the error log: https://jsfiddle.net/k34t9721/

Comment: This is my php code: https://jsfiddle.net/x5d2x4tk/